# Adding sound to a VB6 program

Tags: vb6, audio

I am graduate student trying to manipulate an existing program. Basiclly, the user is tasked to follow a target around with a joystick. I want the program to have a pulse rate associated with the position of the target. I've managed to find the section in the code where the position is calculated/determined, now I just need to add a conditional so that a particular .wav file plays. I have a smattering of programming experience, I've just never used sound. I'm in Visual Basic 6. I just need a quick instructional on how to add sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [quick sample](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Visual-Basic-1048/play-wav-file-VB6-1.htm) of how to use the Win API to do this. Also, here's a more detailed [answer from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/86281).